# Center label in UIView which has y offset of height of status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am quite new to swift and trying to center a label and an image in a UIView which is located at the top of the screen. Currently the label is centered vertically and horizontally since this is the only thing I am able to do right now. As you can see I set autoresizing mask into constraints to false and used centerXAnchor and -YAnchor.

However I actually do not want the label to be in the center of the `PostView` but rather centered with a y offset of the height of the status bar. So it is centered but with no y offset of the height of the statusbar. Consequently, it looks kind of cramped(?): It is very close to the status bar... It looks like this:

[image: centered but with no y offset of the height of the statusbar]

But I would like to have the label (and later also an image) vertically centered in the red box:

[image: The label shall be centered within the red box]

This is the code I have right now (`PostView` class):

```
override init(frame: CGRect){

    super.init(frame: frame)

    //add subview containing name (and image)
    infosContainerView.frame = frame
    addSubview(infosContainerView)

    //add sub view containing label to former UIView (infosContainerView)
    infosContainerView.addSubview(infoNameView)
    infoNameView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    infoNameView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

}

//this UIView shall contain the infoNameView and infoImageView
let infosContainerView: UIView = {

    //set properties of controls container view
    let entireInfoView = UIView()
    entireInfoView.backgroundColor = .white

    return entireInfoView

}()


//label and properties of label with name (autoresizingmaskinto constraint set to false)
let infoNameView: UILabel = {

    //set properties of controls container view
    let nameView = UILabel()

    nameView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nameView.backgroundColor = .white

    nameView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 20)

    nameView.text = "Name"
    nameView.textColor = .black
    nameView.textAlignment = .center

    return nameView

}()
```

EDIT:

Jože Ws was close to solving the problem, instead of dividing by 2 one has to divide by 4 although I do not know why...:

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

infosContainerView.addSubview(infoNameView)
infoNameView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
infoNameView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: statusBarHeight/4).isActive = true
```

Screenshot:

[image: Solution]

Comment: Maybe try this? (1) Let the `entireInfoView` be what it appear to be - a subview of the main view, top anchor be the top of the main view, and white. (2) Let the `nameView` be a subview of the main view also.... setting it's `backgroundColor` to `UIColor.clear`, and it's top anchor to the main view's "margin" top.

Comment: However I actually do not want the label to be in the center of the PostView but rather centered with a y offset of the height of the status bar. So it is centered but with no y offset of the height of the statusbar. Can you please explain it with an image?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `centerYAnchor` constraint init with

```
// infoNameView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

   let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
   infoNameView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: statusBarHeight/2).isActive = true
```

This will add an offset to `centerYAnchor` equal to the value of the `statusBarHeight`

Comment: This adds a too large offset... I will edit a screenshot of it into your answer

Comment: you need to offset half the status bar height `statusBarHeight/2`

Comment: Tried that too, still too large and it didn't look centered, either :/

Comment: is it not moving it closer to the centre?

Comment: Yes, it is moving closer

Comment: can you share the screenshot please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145313/discussion-between-joze-ws-and-moritz).

Comment: How do you want me to share it?